# Push-Notifications not working / Heroku-mLab

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

I haved moved an iOS app from Parse.com to Parse-Server on Heroku. Here is what I have in the main.js cloud code file:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave
("Shop", function(request, response)
 {
 var queryConfig,historicOrderVal;

 var queryConfig = new Parse.Query("Configuration");
 queryConfig.find({
                  success: function(resultConf) {
                  .......
                  newShopAnnounce();
                  response.success();
                  },
                  error: function() {
                  var reptMsg="The Configuration-UPDATE procedure failed for some reason.";
                  console.log(reptMsg);
                  response.error(reptMsg);
                  }
                  });
  });


function newShopAnnounce()
{
    var reptMsg="Now inside newShopAnnounce.";
    console.log(reptMsg);
    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo('deviceType', 'ios');

    Parse.Push.send({
                    where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
                    data: {alert: "NEWSHOP"}
                    }, {
                    success: function() {},
                    error: function(error) {
                    throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
                    }
                    });
}
```

I mainly works except for the fact that I do not see any NOTIFICATION coming (in the iOS app).
I can see in the logs that the newShopAnnounce() function is called, but it doesn't seem to send anything.

If I change the Parse.Push.send() call to:

```
Parse.Push.send({
                where: pushQuery, // Set our Installation query
                data: {alert: "NEWSHOP"}
                }, {
                success: function() {},
                error: function(error) {
                throw "Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message;
                },
                useMasterKey: true
                });
```

I get this:

```
app[web.1]: Now inside newShopAnnounce.
app[web.1]: info: beforeSave triggered for Shop for user Xacb6CzuH9:
app[web.1]:   Input: {....}
app[web.1]:   Result: {"object":{....}} className=Shop, triggerType=beforeSave, user=Xacb6CzuH9
app[web.1]: error: Error generating response. ParseError { code: 115, message: 'Missing push configuration' } code=115, message=Missing push configuration
app[web.1]: [object Object]
heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/classes/Configuration/XYZABC" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=27558d44-d2f5-4a8a-bfef-b85ea4bff9fa fwd="54.158.219.143" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=161ms status=200 bytes=522
2016-11-25T06:43:38.483058+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/logout" host=myapp.herokuapp.com request_id=123456-7718-4cf9-f54f-123456 fwd="106.130.42.63" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=173ms status=200 bytes=483
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing `useMasterKey: true` in your send method.

Please see following for your reference 
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/401

It seems you are missing push configuration. Please add following in your configuration

```
 push: {
android: {
  senderId: '', // The Sender ID of GCM
  apiKey: '' // The Server API Key of GCM
},
ios: {
  pfx: '', // The filename of private key and certificate in PFX or PKCS12 format from disk  
  passphrase: '', // optional password to your p12
  cert: '', // If not using the .p12 format, the path to the certificate PEM to load from disk
  key: '', // If not using the .p12 format, the path to the private key PEM to load from disk
  bundleId: '', // The bundle identifier associate with your app
  production: false // Specifies which environment to connect to: Production (if true) or Sandbox
}
```

}

for example:

```
push: {
    ios: [
        {
            pfx: 'file/***_APNs_Distribution_Certificate.p12', // Dev PFX or P12
            bundleId: 'com.***.***',
            production: true // Dev
        },
        {
            pfx: 'file/***_APNs_Development_Certificate.p12', // Dev PFX or P12
            bundleId: 'com.***.***'',
            production: false // Dev
        }
    ]
},
```

Also refer https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push for more.

Comment: It seems you are right, but I am probably missing more. After trying out your suggestion, I updated my post, please take a look. You may have more to say.

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I have to renew my .p12 file right?

Comment: @Michel, yes if expired. Then include it into your heroku server and add path to push configuration.

Comment: I have spent quite some time following your suggestion and what I could find in the links you mentioned. But it is still not working at this point. I made a new post for that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815928/difficulties-sending-push-notifications-parse-server-heroku

Comment: You put me on track. Thanks. I got the final answer, to make it work, with the post mentioned in my previous comment.